# Swapping the public_html folder for quick website change

Tags: cpanel, vps, whm, public-html

I have two versions of the site which I have to swap really fast, multiple times.

In my home directory, I have:

```
drwxr-x---  8 lorem  nobody      4096 Jul 12 20:50 public_html/
drwxr-x---  3 lorem  nobody      4096 Jul 13 12:59 public_html_3.0/
```

`public_html` holds the current website, `public_html_3.0` holds the new website.

I wish to replace the two by doing:

```
//move the complete current site to another tmp location
mv public_html public_html_2.0 
//move the new site in place
mv public_html_3.0 public_html
```

After trying it on a test account, I get a **Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.** error.

I have made sure that the public_html_*** folders have identical permissions, but I guess it's a symlink issue? Am I trying to do something unthinkable and highly not recommended?

Using VPS WHM/Cpanel with root privileges on CentOs 5.9.

**EDIT**

After some webreading, I have removed `public_html` (moved to temp) and sym-linked `public_html -> public_html_3.0` resulting in:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 lorem nobody           15 Jul 13 14:11 public_html -> public_html_3.0/
drwxr-x---  3 lorem nobody      4096 Jul 13 12:59 public_html_2.0/
drwxr-x---  2 lorem nobody      4096 Jul 13 14:02 public_html_3.0/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 lorem lorem            11 Jul  9  2012 www -> public_html/
```

Still the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the public_html as you have mentioned above is not a big issue.

> mv public_html public_html_2.0
>   mv public_html_3.0 public_html

These are harmless commands if you are aware what you are actually doing.

Make sure that both directories are having 750 permission.

> chmod 750 public_html*

Then make sure that the files inside both directories are having correct permissions.

> find /home/user/public_html/ -type f -exec chmod -R 644 {} \;
>   find /home/user/public_html_3.0/ -type f -exec chmod -R 644 {} \;
>
> find /home/user/public_html/ -type d -exec chmod -R 755 {} \;
>   find /home/user/public_html_3.0/ -type d -exec chmod -R 755 {} \;

Also make sure that the ownership also correct. Change those recursively

> chown -R lorem: /home/user/public_html/*
>   chown -R lorem: /home/user/public_html_3.0/*

In case if you are using suphp handler, you can use lorem:nobody also. Let us know if that helped you.

Comment: Thanks man, this would definitely work. I have spent hours in the learn=>trial=>error cycle, and came up with a similar workflow on my own. Will post my solution below, but yours is a more in-depth view of what's going on, which is great.

Answer (score 1):

The error I was experiencing *(Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.)* was a misplaced root folder of the new site, not a filesystem issue. The new site was actually located in `~/public_html_3.0/public_html/`, because I unzipped it wrong. The new sym-link I put in place, `public_html => public_html_3.0`, was now pointing to a folder without an index file, hence the error.

---

**Alternative solution**

Leo Prince's answer is right, but I will offer an alternative solution with a single-command switch, which also worked for me (explained for newbs like myself):

This solution requires you to have FollowSymlinks enabled for the server or this specific VirtualHost and assumes your vhost is pointing to /home/user/public_html (~/public_html). See accepted answer for permission/ownership instructions.

Let's assume that your **old site** is in `~/public_html` and your **new site** is in `~/app2`.

```
-public_html
   -index.html
   -other.html
-app2
   -index.html
   -other_new.html
```

First, copy your old site to a new directory:

```
# mkdir app1
# cp -a public_html/. app1/.
// -a option copies recursively with permissions/owners/groups 
// but doesn't follow symbolic links
```

Then move (rename) the public_html to a temporary directory and then create a *symbolic link* from public_html to the old app.

```
# mv public_html public_html_bak
// moves the public_html "out of way"
# ln -s app1 public_html
// creates a symbolic-link
# ls -l
drwxr-x---  user nobody app1/
drwxr-x---  user nobody app2/
lrwxr-x---  user nobody public_html -> app1/
drwxr-x---  user nobody public_html_bak/
```

This makes ~/public_html POINT to ~/app1. [Read more on symbolic links](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-creating-symbolic-link-ln-command/). The server sees public_html, but the files are from app1.

If it don't work, go back to previous state:

```
# rm public_html 
//// use rm, NOT rmdir, since it's a symlink, not a dir
# mv public_html_bak public_html
// return backup to previous location
```

If it works, the instant you wish to switch to the new site (app2), you need to change the symbolic link to point to the app2 directory:

```
# rm public_html; ln -s app2 public_html
// remove existing link, create new link with a single line (instant change)
# ls -l
drwxr-x---  user nobody app1/
drwxr-x---  user nobody app2/
lrwxr-x---  user nobody public_html -> app2/
drwxr-x---  user nobody public_html_bak/
```

Although this is approximately the same as doing two folder renames in a row, it makes for a clean review of app versions, which is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
# ls -l
drwxr-x---  user nobody app2.3/
drwxr-x---  user nobody app3.0/
drwxr-x---  user nobody app3.1/
drwxr-x---  user nobody app3.2b/
lrwxr-x---  user nobody public_html -> app3.0/ <- the current active version

# rm public_html; ln -s app3.1 public_html
/// a one-line switch to a different app version
/// first remove the symbolic link; then create new
```

Of course, all the app directories have to have proper permissions, as described in the accepted answer above and the owner:group of the directories have to be the same as the original public_html. Also, the symbolic link must belong to the same user:group with same permissions in case your server configuration allows only symlinks from the same user.

Note that for removing the symbolic link, you should use `rm`, not `rmdir`, since it would fail if you are trying to remove an actual directory.

I'm still learning *NIX, so there might be some issues with this solution I am unaware of. But for frequent version changes, this works like magic :)

Comment: Well explained Vanja. One edit may be useful. Use "cp -a public_html/ app1/" instead of "cp -r public_html/ app1/". Because the -a option does the job of -r(recursive) and -p(preserves permission and ownership)